# PHP MySQL Prepared Statement Join Error

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli, prepared-statement

**Update:** Please see below; I have removed all abstraction and created a plain PHP script but still get the same error.  Please see 'ANOTHER update' below for more information...

**Original Post:** I have a query which has been correctly formed through a database abstraction layer.  The query is the following:

```
SELECT 5c9_dpd_users.id, 5c9_dpd_users.username, 5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id,  
5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms.usergroup_name, 5c9_dpd_users.email FROM 5c9_dpd_users LEFT JOIN
5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms ON 5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms.id = 5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id 
ORDER BY username asc
```

If I generate the same query but run it as a prepared statement which parameterises the second operand of the WHERE clause as below, I get incorrect results.  I am certain that the statement itself is correct and that I am running the MySQLi prep. statement functions in the right order.  The prepared statement query is below:

```
SELECT 5c9_dpd_users.id, 5c9_dpd_users.username, 5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id, 
5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms.usergroup_name, 5c9_dpd_users.email FROM 5c9_dpd_users LEFT JOIN 
5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms ON 5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms.id = ? ORDER BY username asc
```

This query seems to convert the `5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id` that is parameterized to simply '5', since running the query retrieves the right columns from the `SELECT` clause but returns the same `usergroup_name` for all results - this usergroup name matches the usergroup name for the result that has a `5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms.id` of `5`.

I am binding parameters dynamically (`call_user_func_array()`).  In this instance, I tell it to bind the `?` parameter as an `i`.  I thought perhaps this made it convert the `5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id` to a `5` for some reason, but I have tried all three other data types (`s`,`b` and `d`) with no luck.

NB: I have used my database abstraction layer without problem many times, although this IS the first instance in which it has run a join (it has only been recently developed).  To reiterate, the query returns the correct result through PHP and the MySQL console if it is not parameterized, but if given a `?` through the PHP prepared statement functions, the results are incorrect, as described above.

If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it.  I've been up all night googling for help on this matter, and I can't find any similar instance documented anywhere.  Thank you.

**Edit (provides PHP code):**

```
$stmt->select_prep(array('users.id', 'users.username', 'users.cms_usergroup_id', 'usergroups_cms.usergroup_name', 'users.email'), array('users'));
$stmt->left_join_prep('usergroups_cms');
$stmt->on_prep('usergroups_cms.id', '=', 'users.cms_usergroup_id', 'i');

$stmt->order($column, $asc_desc);
$stmt->execute_prep();
```

The query is now executed, and all I have to do is call $stmt->fetch_prep(), a wrapping method that basically retrieves a result set.  The query that this client code generates was given above as the second - the parameterized - query I gave as an example.

I printed out some debugging code in my $stmt->execute_prep() method and the parameter that gets bound to the query appears correctly as:

```
Array
(
  [0] => i
  [1] => 5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id
)
```

This means it is binding one parameter (key 1) as an int (key 0).  I have also tried binding it as a string, double and blob, to no effect.

**ANOTHER Update:**

I created a test script to completely remove my database abstraction layer, and the results are the same: no cms usergroup name is returned.  Here is the script:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'frame');

$q = "SELECT ac9_dpd_users.id, ac9_dpd_users.username, ac9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id, 
ac9_dpd_usergroups_cms.usergroup_name, ac9_dpd_users.email 
FROM ac9_dpd_users 
LEFT JOIN ac9_dpd_usergroups_cms 
ON ac9_dpd_usergroups_cms.id = ? 
ORDER BY username asc";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $param);
$param = 'ac9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id';
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($a, $b, $c, $d, $e);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "id: $a <br>un: $b <br>id: $c <br>cms name: $d <br>email: $e<br><br>";
}

$stmt->close();
unset($mysqli);
?>
```

*Output:*

```
id: 7 
un: ADD 
id: 1 
cms name: 
email: test@test.com

id: 1 
un: New User 
id: 2 
cms name: 
email: test@test.com
```

etc

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

There is a warning in there about using call_user_func_array() in combination with binding parameters to statements. Do you think this may be affecting you?

Comment: I don't think so, since passing a non-reference parameter results in a fatal/warning error (I forgot which, exactly).

Comment: Can you show some of the code you are using to bind parameters? Who knows, you may have missed something in there.

Comment: I'll show what I can; it's all abstracted, however, so it won't be entirely clear, I'm afraid...

Comment: Is 5 in some way the first usergroup id? Like, it seems that it is set once and then not altered?

Comment: No, in the 5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms table (ac9_etc actually, now) the id is a primary key, thus incrementing from 1 onwards.  In the users table, cms_usergroup_id is a foreign key referring to the aforementioned primary key; none of these values actually have a usergroup_id of 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm just a bit picky but I wouldn't start a table/field name with a digit. Use a letter or surround these weird names with backtick (`` ` ``). It should work.

**Edit  (according to your question changes)**

Some spot of your edited script sound alerting to me:

```
     ...
     ON ac9_dpd_usergroups_cms.id = ? 
     ...
     $stmt->bind_param('i', $param);
     $param = 'ac9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id';
```

As reported into the php manual, [mysqli::prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) accepts parameters into where clause and does not permit
to change the columns name of the query.

Furthermore doing a integer bind of a string should convert the value to a number before inserting it into the prepared query and your $params should be converted to 0.

Issue a [sqlstate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.sqlstate.php) statement to check what is going with the query just after your execute:

```
...
$stmt->execute();
$sqlError = $stmt->sqlstate();
if($sqlError != '00000') die($sqlError);
...
```

A possible solution:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'frame');

$q = "SELECT ac9_dpd_users.id, ac9_dpd_users.username, ac9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id, 
ac9_dpd_usergroups_cms.usergroup_name, ac9_dpd_users.email 
FROM ac9_dpd_users 
LEFT JOIN ac9_dpd_usergroups_cms 
ON ac9_dpd_usergroups_cms.id = ac9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id 
ORDER BY username asc";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($a, $b, $c, $d, $e);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "id: $a <br>un: $b <br>id: $c <br>cms name: $d <br>email: $e<br><br>";
}

$stmt->close();
unset($mysqli);
?>
```

Comment: I have renamed the table names (and my queries changed accordingly) but now, NO usergroup name is retrieved...

Comment: I've reproduced the above myself several times but was not sure why the placeholder was not working; knowing that I cannot change the column name of a query certainly explains why my attempts were producing unexpected results!  To solve the problem as it relates to my DB abstraction layer, I've added in another parameter that must be provided by client code in all WHERE and ON clauses that states whether the parameter is to be placeholdered or not!

Thanks very much for the clarification!